# Why am I getting an IndexOutofBoundsException?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm in beginning programming doing my final project using a Swing GUI form. Here's what causes me the problems

```
if (generated.get(round) == 1)
```

It doesn't matter what number it is, any statement like that gives me the IndexOutOfBoundsException. Can you guys help? (The startButton is located in the middle)

**It's `round` that's messing me up, but I have no idea why it's messing up the call**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class finalProject extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form finalProject
 */
public finalProject() {
    initComponents();
    // declare colors in array
    color [0] = "blue";
    color [1] = "red";
    color [2] = "green";
    color [3] = "orange";
    color [4] = "silver";

    // make sure leaderboard is clear
    leaderboardNum.clear();
    leaderboardName.clear();

    // no idea what this does
    finalProject.this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
```

took out the code here purposefully

```
 }// </editor-fold>

private void resetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    // clear all queues and data except for colors
    leaderboardNum.clear();
    leaderboardName.clear();
    generated.clear();
}                                           

private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    // assume the person hasn't failed yet
    failed = false;

    // check if name entered
    if (nameBox.getText().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Put in a name or nickname", "Try again", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else
    {
        // keep looping pattern until person fails
        do
        {                
            // begin generating random numbers for pattern
            generated.add((int) (Math.random() * 5));

            if (generated.get(round) == 0) // if the # is blue
            {
                // flash blue button or do something special
                blueButton.setVisible(false);

                // make loop to count time
                for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < 200; loop1++);

                // bring blue button back
                blueButton.setVisible(true);

                // check if they click the blue button
                if (blueButton.isSelected())
                {
                    //correct goes up one
                    correct++;

                }

                else
                {
                    // if they hit the wrong button, it resets the random & records score
                    generated.clear();

                    leaderboardName.add(nameBox.getText());
                    leaderboardNum.add(correct);

                    //show they failed
                    failed = true;
                }
            }

            if (generated.get(round) == 1) // if the # is red
            {
                // flash blue button or do something special
                redButton.setVisible(false);

                // make loop to count time
                for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < 200; loop1++);

                // bring blue button back
                redButton.setVisible(true);

                // check if they click the blue button
                if (redButton.isSelected())
                {
                    //correct goes up one
                    correct++;

                }

                else
                {
                    // if they hit the wrong button, it resets the random & records score
                    generated.clear();

                    leaderboardName.add(nameBox.getText());
                    leaderboardNum.add(correct);

                    //show they failed
                    failed = true;
                }
            }

            if (generated.get(round) == 2) // if the # is green
            {
                // flash blue button or do something special
                greenButton.setVisible(false);

                // make loop to count time
                for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < 200; loop1++);

                // bring blue button back
                greenButton.setVisible(true);

                // check if they click the blue button
                if (greenButton.isSelected())
                {
                    //correct goes up one
                    correct++;

                }

                else
                {
                    // if they hit the wrong button, it resets the random & records score
                    generated.clear();

                    leaderboardName.add(nameBox.getText());
                    leaderboardNum.add(correct);

                    //show they failed
                    failed = true;
                }
            }

            if (generated.get(round) == 3) // if the # is orange
            {
                // flash blue button or do something special
                orangeButton.setVisible(false);

                // make loop to count time
                for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < 200; loop1++);

                // bring blue button back
                orangeButton.setVisible(true);

                // check if they click the blue button
                if (orangeButton.isSelected())
                {
                    //correct goes up one
                    correct++;

                }

                else
                {
                    // if they hit the wrong button, it resets the random & records score
                    generated.clear();

                    leaderboardName.add(nameBox.getText());
                    leaderboardNum.add(correct);

                    //show they failed
                    failed = true;
                }
            }

            if (generated.get(round) == 4) // if the # is silver
            {
                // flash blue button or do something special
                silverButton.setVisible(false);

                // make loop to count time
                for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < 2000; loop1++);

                // bring blue button back
                silverButton.setVisible(true);

                // check if they click the blue button
                if (silverButton.isSelected())
                {
                    //correct goes up one
                    correct++;

                }

                else
                {
                    // if they hit the wrong button, it resets the random & records score
                    generated.clear();

                    leaderboardName.add(nameBox.getText());
                    leaderboardNum.add(correct);

                    //show they failed
                    failed = true;
                }
            }

            // when game finishes, next round goes
            round++;

        } while (failed == false);
    }
}                                           

private void scoreButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    // declare certain variables
    boolean sorted;
    int pass = 0, numTemp = 0;
    String nameTemp;

    // clear generated queue
    generated.clear();

    // hide all pictures and color buttons, show scores in scoreBox

    // make sure the thing is cleared already
    scoreBox.setText("");

    //check if no scores
    if (leaderboardNum.isEmpty())
    {
        scoreBox.setText("Go play the game and come back later!");
    }

    else
    {
        //bubble sort by score

        do
        {  
            // assume its sorted unless proven other wise
            sorted = true;

            // update pass
            pass++;

            // loop through score arraylist
            for (int sortLoop = 0; sortLoop < leaderboardNum.size() - pass; sortLoop++)
            {
                if (leaderboardNum.get(sortLoop) < leaderboardNum.get(sortLoop + 1))
                {
                    // switch scores
                    numTemp = leaderboardNum.remove(sortLoop);
                    leaderboardNum.set(sortLoop, leaderboardNum.remove(sortLoop + 1));
                    leaderboardNum.set(sortLoop + 1, numTemp);

                    // switch names
                    nameTemp = leaderboardName.remove(sortLoop);
                    leaderboardName.set(sortLoop, leaderboardName.remove(sortLoop + 1));
                    leaderboardName.set(sortLoop + 1, nameTemp);

                    // declare unsorted
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
        while (sorted == false);
    }
}                                           

private void quitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    // exit button
    System.exit(WIDTH);
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(finalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(finalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(finalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(finalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new finalProject().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton blueButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel creatorLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel creditsLabel;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane gameSkeleton;
private javax.swing.JButton greenButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel instructionLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JLabel leaderboardLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel leaderboardPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainGameBackground;
private javax.swing.JTextField nameBox;
private javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton orangeButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel pentagramPicture;
private javax.swing.JButton quitButton;
private javax.swing.JButton redButton;
private javax.swing.JButton resetButton;
private javax.swing.JTextArea scoreBox;
private javax.swing.JButton scoreButton;
private javax.swing.JButton showScoreButton;
private javax.swing.JButton silverButton;
private javax.swing.JButton startButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel thankYouLabel;
// End of variables declaration  

// Declare leaderboard array list, will be sorted from high ==> low
ArrayList<Integer> leaderboardNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> leaderboardName = new ArrayList<String>();

// give each color/spot on pentagram a # in an array, declared at top
String color [] = new String [5];

// random number that makes the color do the thing
ArrayList<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// variable to see if player messed up
boolean failed;

// variable to see if player passed & to count the # of rounds
int correct = 0, round = 0;
```

}

This is supposed to be like a simon says game. If you can recommend any more efficient ways to do, then I'll gladly look into it!

Comment: Can you give use the stacktrace and tell use where in your code the exception occurs? You call `generated.get(...)` a lot of time.

Comment: are you resetting `round`?

Comment: I don't see where `round` is declared, and you should check the structure's size before just attempting to get a random value. It might even be better to use a `for` loop or something of the sort for this.

Comment: If any answers helped you, don't forget to accept them by clicked the check mark under the arrows.

Comment: Thomas, 'generated.get(...) == 2' is where the exception occurs 'round' is declared at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [array out of bounds exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

This is coming from `if (generated.get(round) == 1)` because previously you call `generated.clear();` which [removes all elements of your arraylist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29). This means you are trying to access an index in your array which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized the `round` filed to 0. And in you do-while loop you first add value to list as `generated.add((int) (Math.random() * 5));` and the try getting `generated.get(round)` That should work perfectly. If that is not the case you should check whether round is being modified elsewhere. Try printing out value of round and list size before doing get.

However inside your do-while loop based on certain conditions you are clearing the list `generated.clear();` and towards the end of the loop round is incremented. So on second iteration you might be trying to get an index 1 from and list of size 1. Remember the indexing starts from 0 so you are actually trying to fetch 2nd element form a list that has only 1 element. So when you do `generated.clear();` you should reset round to 0 as well.

Answer (score -1):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` happens when you try to access an element outside of an array's size or boundary/

Let's say we have an array of length 5; If we tried to access the element after `4` it will throw that exception.

Comment: Does not answer **why** he got the exception.